# Opening an accordion and collapsing an existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an accordion it works fine, the only thing which I would like is to close an already open accordion if another accordion is clicked on. Currently, the accordion open and close separately but if another is open I want the current one to collapse

HTML CODE

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="head">Products</a>
        <div class="slide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="head">Сlients</a>
        <div class="slide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="head">About</a>
        <div class="slide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS CODE

```
.accordion,
.accordion li .slide ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.accordion li{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.accordion li .slide{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
}
.accordion li.open .slide{
    height:70px;
}
.accordion li .slide ul{
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
```

JQUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.head').on('click', function(){

        //checking if the parent has a class open assigned to it
        if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('open')){

            ///TO CLOSE THE SLIDE//
            $(this).closest('li').find('.slide').animate({'height':0}, 500);
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('open');  
        }
        else{
            ///TO OPEN THE SLIDE////
            //for dynamic height we ind the ul inside the sliding div and target its height
            var autoHeight = $(this).closest('li').find('.slide ul').height();
            //finding the closest slide in the DOM Tree, so that only that slide will open not all of them
            $(this).closest('li').find('.slide').animate({'height':autoHeight}, 500);
            //finding the closest parent of the clicked item so that only that parent will have the class assigned to it
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('open');     
        }

    });
});
```

I have added comments in the jquery code to make it easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You can animate and set height of all `slide` to `0` except the clicked one. see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.head').on('click', function(){
       //variable to store clicked slide
        var $slide;
        var $parentLi = $(this).closest('li');
        //checking if the parent has a class open assigned to it
        if($parentLi.hasClass('open')){

            ///TO CLOSE THE SLIDE//
            $slide = $parentLi.find('.slide');
            $slide.animate({'height':0}, 500);
            $parentLi.removeClass('open');  
        }
        else{
            ///TO OPEN THE SLIDE////
            //for dynamic height we ind the ul inside the sliding div and target its height
            var autoHeight = $parentLi.find('.slide ul').height();
            //finding the closest slide in the DOM Tree, so that only that slide will open not all of them
            $slide = $parentLi.find('.slide');
            $slide.animate({'height':autoHeight}, 500);
            //finding the closest parent of the clicked item so that only that parent will have the class assigned to it
            $parentLi.addClass('open');     
        }
        //close all slides except the clicked one
        $('.slide').not($slide).animate({'height':0}, 500);
        $('.head').closest('li').not($parentLi).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/649xb3ot/1/)**

Comment: It works the first time only, when done again, the already open accordion collapses but the clicked accordion does not open

Comment: I got the problem. We need to remove `open` class from all parent `li`s of already opened accordians. I have updated my answer, please have a look over it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Before this comment:

```
///TO OPEN THE SLIDE////
```

Just add this code:

```
$("li.open .head").trigger("click");
```

Then the `.open` `li` will close.

Comment: And all the other closed ones will open.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. I don't think so.

Comment: The click handler says "Is it open? If so, close it. Otherwise, open it." If you trigger the click handler on *all of them* then that logic is going to be applied to all of them, and any of the closed ones will get opened. That's what the code does.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. Where am I saying _all of them_?

Comment: In your code. What do you think `$("li.open .head")` selects?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. The elements which have class `head` that are inside the `li` which contains the `open` class.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I'm being an idiot, was thinking that class is on all of them but obviously it's only on the ones that are actually open. Good thing I have a vacation coming up.

Comment: It happens.. I would like vacation too.. =)

Answer (score 0):

Along with Guedes fix, you can even use jquery slideUp and slideDown to avoid getting height dynamically and remove some css code too to make code more simpler.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.head').on('click', function(){
        //checking if the parent has a class open assigned to it
        if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('open')){

            ///TO CLOSE THE SLIDE//
            $(this).closest('li').find('.slide').slideUp();
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('open');  
        }
        else{
            $(this).closest('ul').find("li.open .head").trigger("click");
            ///TO OPEN THE SLIDE////
            //finding the closest slide in the DOM Tree, so that only that slide will open not all of them
            $(this).closest('li').find('.slide').slideDown();
            //finding the closest parent of the clicked item so that only that parent will have the class assigned to it
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('open');     
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.accordion,
.accordion li .slide ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.accordion li{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.accordion li .slide{
    display: none;
}
.accordion li .slide ul{
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
```